# jQuery slide: gradient background object's rounded corner shadow in Chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, slidedown, css

I'm using jQuery `slideUp()` and `slideDown()` for an object that has a `-webkit-gradient` background, rounded corners, and a `box-shadow`.

For some reason this exact combination doesn't work very well in Chrome.

My spec says to have the two bottom corners be square (border-radius 0) since it will be aligned against something below, but the top two corners are to be rounded (border-radius large).

http://jsfiddle.net/jdY3W/6/

The problem is that during the `slideUp()` and `slideDown()` animations — only during these transitions, not when they're complete — the shadow appears square in Chrome.

Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xGn12.png

A couple of things I've realized:

1. Most combinations of border-radius values are okay, but the values I need are not. Here are some examples I've tested that are OK:

   ```css
   border-radius: 10px 20px 20px 20px;
   border-radius: 20px 20px 30px 0;
   border-radius: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
   border-radius: 20px 20px 19px 19px;
   ```

   And some that aren't:

   ```css
   border-radius: 10px 20px 20px 25px;
   border-radius: 20px 20px 0 0; /* what I need */
   border-radius: 20px 20px 30px 30px;
   ```
2. Everything seems to work fine in Safari and FF.

Anyone have any thoughts?

Comment: Which version of Chrome? Is it one that still uses `-webkit-gradient`? It works fine for me on Chromium 22.

Comment: Version 23.0.1271.95 (Mac), Version 23.0.1271.95 m (PC). I've added a link to an image of what's happening.

Comment: This same issue is still also happening for Version 24.0.1312.49 beta-m (PC).

Comment: 24.0.1312.52 and 24.0.1312.56 (both Mac) still exhibit the same behavior, but 25.0.1364.45 beta-m (PC) seems to look correct. It's looking like it's a bug that will be fixed.

Comment: Yep, definitely a bug. I had the same problem in Chromium a lot, too, when using CSS3 transitions.